# simplenodal confirm inside a before jstree event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

My basic need is to either stopImmediatePropagation() or not in jstree - based on user confirmation dialog.  For example, the user checked a top-level node and my code realizes that it can be dangerous for him to do that - and asks for confirmation.  If the user says 'no', the stop will keep the check from actually happening.  I want this to be nodal so the user is forced to answer this dialog first.

SimpleNodal 'confirm' looked like a good solution.  Everything works except the stop propagation.  Stepping in firebug, the cause is that the return is executed in the jstree.stopPropagation() because this.originalEvent is undefined.

An easier way or workaround would be much appreciated.

Snippet from jquery.js - this return is executed instead of finishing the stop:

```
stopPropagation: function() {
  this.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;
  var e = this.originalEvent;
  if ( !e ) {
    return;
  }
```

Errant code starts here - the stop is executed, but the return above is taken:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link type='text/css' href='confirm/css/demo.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
<link type='text/css' href='confirm/css/confirm.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='confirm/js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='confirm/js/confirm.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo1" style="float:left;width:50%;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="" id='a' >aaa</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" id='b' >bbb</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $("#demo1").jstree({ 
            "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "dots": true,
            "icons": true,
            "url": "themes/default/style.css"
          },

            "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui", "checkbox" ],
            "checkbox": { "override_ui" : true, "checked_parent_open" : false }

        })
        .bind("before.jstree", function (event1, data) {
            console.log(data.func);
            if(data.func === "uncheck_node") {                 // a node was unchecked
                if (typeof(data.args[0]) == "string") return;
                id = data.args[0].parentNode.id;
                if (id == 'a') {
                    **//Uncomment these 2 and the stop works**
                    **//event1.stopImmediatePropagation();**
                    **//return false;**
                    return(
                        confirm('Any Luck', function(isYes) {
                            if (!isYes) {
                                event1.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                return false;
                            } else
                                return true;
                        })
                    );
                }
            }
            if(data.func === "check_node") {                   // a node was unchecked
                $(function(){console.log('hello world');});
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
    <div id='confirm'>
        <div class='message'></div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <div class='no'>No</div>
            <div class='yes'>Yes</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style='display:none'>
        <img src='confirm/img/confirm/header.gif' alt='' />
        <img src='confirm/img/confirm/button.gif' alt='' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found the the simple confirm works per another vakata post, so I'm eliminating simpleNodal for now.  Here's the working code:        .bind("before.jstree", function (event1, data) {
            if(data.func === "check_node") {
if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to check?")) {
                    event1.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false;
                }